# Retrieve current mixer levels with WMI?

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, audio, wmi

Is there a way to get Windows audio mixer levels using WMI? For example, to get the current line input level.

Ideally this would work on XP and Vista, although I'm aware the audio subsystem is completely different between the two, so I might need a different solution for each.

**Edit**: suggestions in any language will do.

Comment: so "non wmi" is ok here?

Comment: for windows vista and above, you can use this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200825/getting-individual-windows-application-current-volume-output-level-as-visualized?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope - none of the audio controls are exposed through WMI.

Comment: Thanks for sorting me out again Larry!

Answer (score 0):

Vista re-vamped the audio system, and there is not any good samples out there for controlling lines in the mixer yet, that I have found.