# Can you get/set the System Sounds volume or Windows OS master volume via Powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell, winapi, windows-10

It's Win10 or 11 and I've seen the below for increasing/decreasing the volume 2% each time it's called, however I'd like to get/set the `System Sounds` volume, or the `Device (master) Volume`. Is that possible in Powershell?

```
const uint WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;
const uint APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 0xA0000;
const uint APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 0x90000;
const uint APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000; 

Win32.Win32.SendMessage(handy, WM_APPCOMMAND, handy, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);

Win32.Win32.SendMessage(handy, WM_APPCOMMAND, handy, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[The AudioDeviceCmdlets module](https://github.com/frgnca/AudioDeviceCmdlets) in powershell that can be used to manage sound devices and volume level.

And you could also try to use [Core Audio APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/coreaudio/core-audio-apis-in-windows-vista?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to control the system volume. And then you could access the `[Audio]::Volume` property from PowerShell.

I suggest you could refer to the threads:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19348221/11872808

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31751275/11872808