# Creating a script to disable Left speaker In Control Panel In Windows

Tags: c, windows, automation, command-line-interface, controlpanel

My left speaker is torn , I can't replace it right now .There is a appaling sound when i play media .A way around is to go to the  Control Panel >Hardware and Sound >Change system sounds > Right Click on the speaker (Playback tab) >Properties >Levels >Balance >Left Slider to zero . This makes it so sound only plays from the right speaker which works fine for me .BUT , I need to plug in heaphones for when I am working (they are not in all the time)and need to revert sound settings back to the default which gets annoying fast . I want to create a script ( in the simplest way possible) that when executed can navigate the settings and turn the left speaker to zero .Even a way to do it through the terminal (if a script is not practical would be appreaciated ). A desktop shortcut to quickly do the mundane work . Programming wise I don't have much .I am a beginner in C,and completed cs50  but I am always up for a challenge . If I can get a roadmap for how to do it , I will be attempting to do it best I can.

Comment: Related: [Change audio level from powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355891/change-audio-level-from-powershell)

Comment: Programmatically the Windows API is discussed in [IChannelAudioVolume interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nn-audioclient-ichannelaudiovolume), with a particular function [`IChannelAudioVolume::SetChannelVolume`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nf-audioclient-ichannelaudiovolume-setchannelvolume).

Comment: You might be interested in [SoundVolumeView v2.40 - View / change sound volume on Windows from command-line or GUI](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html)

Comment: why not just disconnect the speaker?

Comment: It's a laptop ! I don't know how I failed to mention that . yeah

Comment: I suppose I could open it up and disconnect just the left speaker . That might actually be the easiest solution . Will try it tomorrow . Let's see how it goes