# Control application audio stream panning by Process ID in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, audio, wasapi, cscore

I wish to control the panning (volume level of the left/right audio channel) of an application by process ID in C#.

I have found similar questions, but they all control the stream volume and cannot 'pan' the two channels for stereo streams.

> [Controling Volume Mixer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306048/controling-volume-mixer)
>   [Controlling Application's Volume: By Process-ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938934/controlling-applications-volume-by-process-id)
>   [Getting individual windows application current volume output level as visualized in audio Mixer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200825/getting-individual-windows-application-current-volume-output-level-as-visualized)
>   [Trying to build a simple c# app to control my volume mixer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126407/trying-to-build-a-simple-c-sharp-app-to-control-my-volume-mixer)

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 C# on Windows 7.

The ultimate goal is to have an application that will pan the audio from applications based upon their window location of my triple monitor setup.

Please assist.

Edit: It appears all I need to use is IChannelAudioVolume instead of ISimpleAudioVolume but I have no idea how to use/find these magical GUID's or rewrite the code with my basic understanding of C#

IChannelAudioVolume http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371023%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
ISimpleAudioVolume http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Interesting idea. I'm affraid it might involve writing a custom audio driver, though... The volume mixer doesn't seem to support different panning for different applications.

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/sound/article.php/c10931/Windows-Mixer-Control-in-C.htm), it may give you some ideas.

Comment: As far as I know, Sessions can only support ISimpleAudioVolume so it is not possible to adjust their volume levels on a per channel basis.