# Detect is any audio playing

Tags: c#, winapi, audio, windows-ce

I want to detect is any audio playing from any application using Windows API functions like waveout... or mixer functions. I am going to use it in the program I am writing for *Windows CE 6* using C#. Note that I am programming Windows CE so there are some limits, and I don't want to use DirectX.

Comment: Sounds pretty cool! Did you have a question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know if a sound is playing using c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829571/how-to-know-if-a-sound-is-playing-using-c)

Comment: @DrewJordan I want to know how to do this.

Comment: can you try a google search what have you actually done on your own besides stating what you want..?

Comment: @MethodMan I searched a lot.

Comment: then you should have found some examples on DirectX then ..

Comment: I can't use DirectX. As I mentions in question I want to use windows API.

Comment: [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2013/09/26/getting-peak-meters-and-volume-settings-for-all-apps-and-audio-devices-on-the-system.aspx) would appear to answer your question if you were writing your code in C++.  Given that you are using C#, and do not want to use DirectX, you will most likely need to write similar code that call the Windows API's directly using PInoke and import the COM libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Need more specification on the device that will be used.
It's not wise to use other things - DirectX is well prepared for common problems, that you will have.

Also please look at Platform Builder - maybe this is more complex but you will know what kind of IN/OUT's you will be using.