# How can I determine the process that playing sound via C#?

Tags: c#, windows, audio

I use one music player and I'd like to develop a plugin for it in C#.
The plugin should stop playing, when others programs start playing, for example youtube in Chrome or Skype.
Is it possible to monitor all sound sources in Windows via C# or any other language?

Comment: Would this help....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829571/how-to-know-if-a-sound-is-playing-using-c