# Monitoring the output volume

Tags: c#, audio

I'm really hoping that this isn't going to be too complicated.

Basically I want to have a program monitor the OUTPUT of the audio (i.e. what we hear when we play a song, watch a video, or whatever else we do) and output the current audio level based on what's playing.

I've seen countless examples on how to do this with INPUTS (like microphones) but nothing that has worked with outputs.

More specifically I have Winamp hooked up to a local radio audio stream.  So I'm listening to music. What I want is for this program to loop through every, say, 10ms and tell me the current audio level of the song.  So if it's a rock song, it might be super loud during the chorus (i.e. a louder output) vs the verse.  If it's a soft blues song, or whatever, the output obviously won't be as loud.

I know how to do all the loops but, like I said, everything I've seen for the rest of it all has to deal with controlling either the master volume bar (which doesn't help me) or is for inputs.

Is this even possible?  I would assume it is since people write visualization plugins for media players all the time (and it does pretty much exactly what I want to do, only I want it to display it back to me as #s instead of pretty colors).

Comment: I suspect OS and version will be important here. I assume you're on Windows since you're running Winamp - what version?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200825/getting-individual-windows-application-current-volume-output-level-as-visualized) out

Comment: I don't think that will really work the way I want, aaaaahhhhh.