# Controlling Application's Volume & VU Meter

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, naudio

I am using NAudio for a screen recording software I am designing and I need to know if it's possible to not only control the specific application's volume but also display a VU Meter for the application's sound.

I've Googled all over the place and it seems I can only get a VU Meter for the devices currently on my computer and set the volume for those devices.

Even though I am using NAudio, I am open to other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the question in more detail after this question. I have since found the answer so I will leave the answer here for those who stumble upon it. Trying to use NAudio & CSCore has gotten me quite familiar with so please ask if you need further assistance.

This block of code uses CSCore and is a modified and commented version of the answer found here:[Getting individual windows application current volume output level as visualized in audio Mixer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200825/getting-individual-windows-application-current-volume-output-level-as-visualized)

```
class PeakClass
{
    static int CurrentProcessID = 0000;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Basically gets your default audio device and session attached to it
        using (var sessionManager = GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow.Render))
        {
            using (var sessionEnumerator = sessionManager.GetSessionEnumerator())
            {
                //This will go through a list of all processes uses the device
                //the code got two line above.
                foreach (var session in sessionEnumerator)
                {
                    //This block of code will get the peak value(value needed for VU Meter)
                    //For whatever process you need it for (I believe you can also check by name
                    //but I found that less reliable)
                    using (var session2 = session.QueryInterface<AudioSessionControl2>())
                    {
                        if(session2.ProcessID == CurrentProcessID)
                        {
                            using (var audioMeterInformation = session.QueryInterface<AudioMeterInformation>())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(audioMeterInformation.GetPeakValue());
                            }
                        }
                    }

                   //Uncomment this block of code if you need the peak values 
                   //of all the processes
                   //
                    //using (var audioMeterInformation = session.QueryInterface<AudioMeterInformation>())
                    //{
                    //    Console.WriteLine(audioMeterInformation.GetPeakValue());
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static AudioSessionManager2 GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow dataFlow)
    {
        using (var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator())
        {
            using (var device = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(dataFlow, Role.Multimedia))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DefaultDevice: " + device.FriendlyName);
                var sessionManager = AudioSessionManager2.FromMMDevice(device);
                return sessionManager;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following code block will allow you to change the volume of the device using NAudio

```
MMDevice VUDevice;

public void SetVolume(float vol)
    {
        if(vol > 0)
        {
            VUDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = false;
            VUDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar = vol;
        }
        else
        {
            VUDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = true;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(vol);
    }
```

I have code from two different libraries only to answer the question I posted directly which was how to both set the volume and get VU Meter values (peak values). CSCore and NAudio are very similar so most of the code here is interchangeable.